# Unwanted <p> tags inserted before and after a rendered $item

Tags: entities, theming

First time creating a [custom template for a field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7).

I've created the `field--field_phone_number.tpl.php` and know it's working.

I'm trying to make it so when a user enters a phone number, it displays as a link with the "tel:" prefix so that readers can click the link on their mobile phones to call directly.

Here's what I have:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><a href="tel:<?php print render($item); ?>"><?php print render($item); ?></a></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only problem is that it actually prints out something like

```
<a href="tel:<p>3035551212</p>">3035551212</a>
```

Where are those `<p>` tags coming from?

I see many posts around about those tags coming from WYSIWYG editors and the like, but I'm not using one of those. I've also seen a suggestion that this is related to a [default line-break converter](https://drupal.org/node/503754), which I'd rather not turn off.

Comment: <a href="tel:<?php print '123'; ?>"><?php print '123'; ?></a> works perfectly.. Problem with render function ?

Comment: I would suggest you use the Telephone module which provides a field with the behavior and output you are after: https://drupal.org/project/telephone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be some better solution of this question but as you are facing of this extra html tag issue inside href, here is solution for this.

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): 
    $phone_link_data = render($item); 
    $phone_link = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($phone_link_data));
    ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><a href="tel:<?php print $phone_link; ?>"><?php print render($item); ?></a></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that did it, thank you. Agree that the [Telephone module](https://drupal.org/project/telephone) will serve me better (thanks, @pontus), but a nice learning exercise. Thanks to all.